# Customize IBM DiffMerge to export a custom Report

Tags: rhapsody, diffmerge

I am using IBM DiffMerge to generate a Report that shows all differences between two .cls files or .sbs files. I was playing with it and I saw that there is a filed in option menu that allows you to change the format of the report, but it implies some keywords, like `$elemname` to print the element's name or `$elemtype` to print its type `$leftonly` or `$rightonly` which show how many differences are in the left diagram or in the right one.

Now, I was wondering if there are more variables like those above, especially one that can print a component's GUID (unique ID in Rhapsody).

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that $GUID will give you what you're looking for.

Under the ReporterPlus installation folder there is a folder named Templates. In it you'll find a file named DiffReport.dpl which you can load it into ReporterPlus for editing like any other template. You must run Rep+ with a command line option so that it loads with the Diffmerge specific schema: 
Reporter.exe /mode=dfm 
After that you can load the Diffmerge template, and edit it to customize the output of DiffMerge reports. When you do, try adding $GUID into the output.

Regards, Simon